# wget, curl, file_get_contents not working over SSL but https does

Tags: php, apache, ssl

I have a PHP Laravel application.

When I type in `https://www.sideprojectors.com`

It works fine.

But when I do

```
wget https://www.sideprojectors.com
```

or

```
curl https://www.sideprojectors.com
```

or create a PHP script that executes

```
file_get_contents('https://www.sideprojectors.com')
```

I get the following error

```
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Now I'm running the above commands directly on the server.

However, if I try to do the same thing on my local machine, it works fine! So on my laptop, if I do

```
curl https://www.sideprojectors.com
```

It's all good.

What's going on here? How can I fix this? Thank you.

[SOLVED]

Just wanted to update with the solution in case if it helps anyone.

In my virtual host, I had something like this

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.1:443>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, I didn't specify my IPv6 address in it. An easy way would be to do

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I have multiple IP addresses on my server, so I specified my IPv6 address so now it looks like

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.1:443 [1:2:3:4]:443>
</VirtualHost>
```

That worked.

Comment: Looks like an SSL cert issue. Try including the `-k` tag: `curl -k https://www.mywebsite.com`. What do you get?

Comment: I get ["Making request failed: SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length."](https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/ZSd7o)

Comment: I'm assuming that your site does not have a valid SSL certificate... it will work locally but you will need to get a valid cert to test in production.

Comment: When you do curl request try add option  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);.